# rollout restart command does not work for my specific deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to restart the pod using ***kubectl rollout restart deployment***  However, it does not restart the existing pod but creates the new pod and terminates it. The command works fine for my other deployments but it does not affect the existing pod just start and terminate the new pod.

Here is the deployment.yaml for the reference:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: plugin
  namespace: xxxxxxx
  uid: xxxxxxxx
  resourceVersion: 'xxxxxxxx'
  generation: 338
  creationTimestamp: '2021-07-01T11:05:55Z'
  labels:
    app: che
    app.kubernetes.io/component: plugin-registry
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: che
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: che-operator
    app.kubernetes.io/name: che
    component: plugin-registry
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '318'
  ownerReferences:
    - apiVersion: xxxxxxx/v1
      kind: CheCluster
      name: xxxxxxxx
      uid: xxxxxxxx
      controller: true
      blockOwnerDeletion: true
    - manager: kube-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2022-07-20T11:55:39Z'
    - manager: manager
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: apps/v1
      time: '2022-07-20T11:55:39Z'

spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: che
      component: plugin-registry
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: che
        app.kubernetes.io/component: plugin-registry
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: che
        app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: che-operator
        app.kubernetes.io/name: che
        component: plugin-registry
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: xxxxxxxx
          image: xxxxxxxx
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP

          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 500m
              memory: 256Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 32Mi
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /plugins/
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 3
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 10
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /plugins/
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 3
            timeoutSeconds: 3
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 10
          terminationMessagePath: /xxxxxxxx
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          securityContext:
            capabilities:
              drop:
                - ALL
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      securityContext: {}
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 25%
      maxSurge: 25%
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
status:
  observedGeneration: 338
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
  readyReplicas: 1
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
    - type: Available
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2022-07-20T11:53:27Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2022-07-20T11:53:27Z'
      reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
      message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    - type: Progressing
      status: 'True'
      lastUpdateTime: '2022-07-20T11:55:39Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2022-02-14T09:08:32Z'
      reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
      message: ReplicaSet has successfully progressed.
```

Comment: That sounds like normal behavior to me.  Deleting pods is pretty routine and in some circumstances it can happen outside your immediate control.

Comment: @DavidMaze it does not affect the pod which is the oldest, it just starts & terminates the new pod instantly. it also does not keep the new pod alive after restart. just the oldest remain there without a restart.

Comment: I have been attempting to reproduce your issue with other deployments, and the command is running well, which tells me the problem is specific to your deployment. My recommendation is to review pod status and logs that will help you to determine what the root cause of your issue is and edit your question to include those details.